# Error al insertar valores a una tabla (Error Code: 1452)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

tengo creadas las siguientes tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE usuario(
    nroCuenta CHAR(12),
    nombreUsuario VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    direccion VARCHAR(45),
    nroMovil VARCHAR(15),
    paisUsuario VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(nroCuenta)
);

CREATE TABLE descarga(
    cuentaUsuario CHAR(12),
    codigoApp VARCHAR(45),
    fechaDescarga DATE NOT NULL,
    puntuacion TINYINT(1),
    comentario VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(cuentaUsuario, codigoApp),
    FOREIGN KEY(cuentaUsuario) REFERENCES usuario(nroCuenta) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(codigoApp) REFERENCES aplicacion(codigo) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CHECK (puntuacion >= 0 AND puntuacion <= 5)
);
```

intento añadir valores a la tabla descarga:

`INSERT INTO descarga VALUES ('UR-9CLSBAMWA', '5CCH5FGFZP', '2019-12-01', 4, 'S/C');`

Pero me aparece:

`` Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tiendaaplicaciones`.`descarga`, CONSTRAINT `descarga_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cuentaUsuario`) REFERENCES `usuario` (`nroCuenta`) ON DELETE CASCADE) ``

Alguién puede ver algún error en la definición de las claves foráneas?

Comment: Tus raciones están mal definidas

Comment: Las llaves primarias solo guardan números o textos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba añadiendo estas instrucciones antes de crear la tabla `descarga`:

```
CREATE TABLE aplicacion(
    codigo varchar(45) PRIMARY KEY
  );

INSERT INTO usuario (nroCuenta) VALUES
  ('UR-9CLSBAMWA');

INSERT INTO aplicacion (codigo) VALUES
  ('5CCH5FGFZP');
```

Por definición, no puedes insertar un dato en `descarga` hasta que no exista un usuario y una aplicación con las que vincularlos. No tenías la `FK` mal definida, sino que te faltaban registros y la clave ajena estaba haciendo su trabajo: impedirte registrar datos que no cumplieran con las restricciones que habías definido.

Comment: Aunque no esté mal definida y MySQL no alegará por eso. Aún así, no se debe pasar las claves primarias a después ser claves foráneas. Definir algo que después no se usará, son malas prácticas.

Comment: Perdona @Synay, no entiendo a qué te refieres... ¿por qué el código de la aplicación no debería ser clave principal?

Comment: Ya lo veo, habia olvidado cargar los datos de la tabla usuario. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que añadir valores a tus tablas padres primero para que puedas añadir a la Hija, en este caso.
tabla usuario con valor en nroCuenta y
tabla aplicacion con valor en codigo.

luego de eso verifica que los tipos de datos de tus dos tablas coincidan, por ejemplo, si codigo tienes char y en la otra tabla está varchar, vas a tener que cambiar alguno para que coincida.

Suerte.

Comment: Si amigo eso mismo era, muchas gracias